# BigQuery is it possible to round PERCENT_RANK() output

Tags: google-bigquery

No reproducible example needed here because the question is straightforward. An example of the output in the row of a column generated using `PERCENT_RANk()` is `0.9900990099009901` and I would love to only show 3-4 decimal places here. The column-creation line in the `SELECT` call is:

```
PERCENT_RANK() OVER (partition by a.zone ORDER BY b.this_num ASC) AS pctile_val,
```

Is this possible with `PERCENT_RANK()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if `PERCENT_RANK()` itself supports rounding, but there should be nothing stopping you from wrapping your call in `ROUND()`, e.g.

```
ROUND(PERCENT_RANK() OVER (partition by a.zone ORDER BY b.this_num ASC), 4) AS pctile_val
```